Does "I juiced the orange" imply we are using a tool like a juicer or blender?
"Juice" is a noun but also a verb.
In the Oxford dictionary,

juice something to get the juice out of fruit or vegetables
Juice two oranges.

If I solely based on the definition of the dictionary, I would understand that "to juice an orange" is a general term for getting juice out of an orange. There're many ways to do it:
-squeeze juice out of an orange
-use a juicer or a blender to get the juice.
I asked people on Quora and some said "to juice an orange" often implies using a tool to do it. If we do it by hand, we say "to squeeze juice".
In addition, I often see these phrase "how to juice a lemon?" or "to juice the fruit in a juicer".
But I don't often see this phrase "to juice fruit into a container".
Is there a good reason why we don't say "I juiced a lemon into a bowl"?
Also, Does "I juiced the orange" imply we are using a tool like a juicer or blender?

no, it does not imply the use of a tool

The reason it implies using a juicer has nothing to do with language, and is just because it's much easier that way. We don't have different words for juicing with a tool and juicing with your bare hands.

If you don't see juice fruit [verb] into a container it's because the fruit juice is already in juice form! So, it's poured into a container.

I find the question slightly odd, since it seems to ignore common sense.
If I say "I wrote my name", does it imply that I used a writing implement like a pen, pencil, or chalk?
No, not really. You can write your name in the dirt with a finger! But if you apply common sense, 99.9% of the time, when someone says "I wrote my name", they did so with a tool for writing.
Similarly you can juice an orange with a fancy machine, or with a simple juicing dish, or even with a fork.  You can even juice an orange just by squeezing it.  But most of the time, if you want to get all juice out of an orange, you will use a tool, even if the tool is just a fork.
That's not English.  That's just common sense.

I. Squeeze vs. Juice (verb)

Does "I juiced the orange" imply using a tool like a juicer or blender?

Let's look at the origins of the verb "juice":

Reference Oxford dictionary
The earliest known use of the verb juice is in the mid 1600s.
OED's earliest evidence for juice is from 1639, in the writing of Thomas Fuller, Church of England clergyman.
juice, v.meanings

Now, the meanings of "squeeze" and "juice":
squeeze: to press and extract juice.
juice: to extract juice.
Since the verb "juice" originated before the invention of the juicer, its original meaning was simply "to extract juice."

II. Why we don’t often say "to juice fruit into a container"

The phrase "I juiced a lemon into a bowl" sounds unusual because we typically specify the tool ("juicer") when discussing "juicing."
Common phrases like "juice in a juicer" emphasize the tool, while "into a container" is less common since it's assumed that juice will be collected somewhere; specifying "a bowl" is usually unnecessary.
